# How to save a back-up folder on a Network Drive?

Tags: excel, vba

Below code works but once I change the `backupFolder` location to a network drive it gives me

> 'runtime 1004' error.

How can I save on the network drive?

```vb
Sub SaveBackUp()

Dim saveDate As Date
Dim saveTime As Variant
Dim formatTime As String
Dim formatDate As String
Dim backupFolder As String

saveDate = Date
saveTime = Time

formatTime = Format(saveTime, "hh.MM.ss")
formatDate = Format(saveDate, "YYYY-MM-DD")

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
backupFolder = "C:\Users\EXAMPLE\Documents\Backup\"
ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs Filename:=backupFolder & Replace(ActiveWorkbook.Name, ".xlsm", "") & " " & "- Backup " & formatDate & " " & formatTime & ".xlsm"
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
ActiveWorkbook.Save
MsgBox "Successfully saved backup-file in path " & backupFolder

End Sub
```

Comment: Do you have write access to the network location? Have you double (triple) checked that the path is accurate?

Comment: What does that network path look like? You could add it to your question for clarity.

Comment: When creating a new file, if the directory doesn't exist, the application will attempt to create the directory. This feature only works for the last directory in the path. If there are 2 directories that don't exist, it will give an error.

Comment: Hi,

Thanks for your answers. 

My directory exists and is:

"L:\FED\EXAMPLE\A\B\C\F\E\1. Financial Accounting\F\G\Dashboard tbv invoicing\Dashboard 2023 (new)\Backup\"

Change some things up, but in essence it's that location. I know for sure it's correct. Any ideas why I'm getting an error? Could it be an authorization issue for VBA? I can manually go to the folder and save a file etc.

Comment: @drkedi ,your path example is not a network drive, It should begins with \\ .I know you see it like "L:\FED\EXAMPLE\A\B\C\F\E\1." on windows explorer ,but it is like a shortcut to your real path. **The easiest way** to find your actual network drive is by creating a new email and drag (using right-click) any file on the network drive and drop on the window of the new email , and chose `create hyperlink here`